# Delete only first occurrence of character using tr

Tags: tr

I want to delete the occurrence of a character in a string only for the first occurrence.

Example:

```
echo "B123_BACK" | tr -d 'B'
```

This results in output:

```
123_ACK
```

How can I delete only the first occurrence of charcater `'B'` so that the output looks like

```
123_BACK
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the `tr` man page, this isn't possible. Why not use `sed` instead:

```
echo "B123_BACK"|sed 's/B//'
```